# Maven wildfly:deploy -P profileX doesn't trigger the right profile

Tags: java, maven

I have 2 profiles in Maven's settings.xml but I cannot trigger them by the -P option, always the second is used:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>wilfly-local</id>
    <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        <properties>
            <wildfly-hostname>127.0.0.1</wildfly-hostname>
            <wildfly-port>zzzz</wildfly-port>
            <wildfly-username>xxx</wildfly-username>
            <wildfly-password>S3cret</wildfly-password>
        </properties>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <id>wildfly-remote</id>
    <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        <properties>
            <wildfly-hostname>192.168.xxx.yyy</wildfly-hostname>
            <wildfly-port>zzzz</wildfly-port>
            <wildfly-username>xxx2</wildfly-username>
            <wildfly-password>S3cret</wildfly-password>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
...
<activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>wildfly-local</activeProfile>
    <activeProfile>wildfly-remote</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>
```

My pom.xml:

```
...
<build>
    <finalName>mvnweb</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1.Final</version>
            <configuration>
                <hostname>${wildfly-hostname}</hostname>
                <port>${wildfly-port}</port>
                <username>${wildfly-username}</username>
                <password>${wildfly-password}</password>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
...
```

The problem is when I try mvn wildfly:deploy -P wildfly-local, Maven deploys the war file on the remote server. 
When I change the order of profiles then the second one is used (I checked it with -X option when I ran it). Both profiles deploys the project properly.
The *activeByDefault* tag do nothing, if I comment it out the result remains the same. 
Can somebody tell me what should I do to get *-P trigger work properly*?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Active_Profiles):

> The final piece of the settings.xml puzzle is the activeProfiles element. This contains a set of activeProfile elements, which each have a value of a profile id. Any profile id defined as an activeProfile will be active, reguardless of any environment settings. If no matching profile is found nothing will happen. For example, if env-test is an activeProfile, a profile in a pom.xml (or profile.xml with a corrosponding id will be active. If no such profile is found then execution will continue as normal.

Since you have both your profiles specified in your settings.xml they are activated both. Second one probably overwrites properties.

You should remove your activeProfiles from settings.xml if you want enable then only by -P CLI argument

```
<activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>wildfly-local</activeProfile>
    <activeProfile>wildfly-remote</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>
```

Comment: Yes, it works! I removed the wildfly-remote only and now the default is the local, and when I want to deploy on the remote server I can use it with -P option. Thanks!